# Chess Board in Metro Style apps

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, chess

I am just playing around with the Metro style apps. I wanted to create a simple chess board using the `UniformGrid` from Wpf but it seems like that it is not supported in Metro style apps. Are there any alternative ways in Metro Style apps to create a chess board?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use an 8x8 Grid?  Eight `RowDefinitions` and Eight `ColumnDefinitions` should get it.

Here's a very brute force method of doing this.  As long as the grid's height and width make it square, the resultant items will be the appropriate proportions.  You could also set the Height of each RowDefinition and the Width of each ColumnDefinition to the same arbitrary value and get it proportional.

For something like this, I might choose to add the controls in the codebehind, versus in the XAML, but that's a choice I leave up to you.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="400" Height="400" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7"/>

    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5"/>
    <Border Background="Ivory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6"/>
    <Border Background="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes I can do that but many people over the internet suggest to use the UniformGrid for WPF which a lot easier as all the cells are of the same size. I think I am gonna use an 8x8 Grid but not sure how to make the sizes uniform(I am very new to the Xaml world) .

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using databinding you can use a WrapGrid with the MaximumRowsOrColumns property set to 8. Then bind to a collection of 64 items that contain the state of the board.

[WrapGrid API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

UniformGrid isn't necessary with ViewBox:

```html
<Window 
    x:Class="MainWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ChessGUI" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Title="Chess GUI" 
    Height="640" 
    Width="640" Background="PaleGreen"
    >
    <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="16" >
        <Grid Background="White" Width="256" Height="256">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="7" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="9" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="11" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="13" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="15" Fill="DarkGray" />

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="7" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="9" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="11" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="13" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="15" Fill="LightGray" />

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="5" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="7" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="9" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="11" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="13" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="15" Fill="DarkGray" />

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="3" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="5" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="7" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="9" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="11" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="13" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="15" Fill="LightGray" />

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="3" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="5" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="7" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="9" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="11" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="13" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="9" Grid.Column="15" Fill="DarkGray" />

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="1" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="3" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="5" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="7" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="9" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="11" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="13" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="11" Grid.Column="15" Fill="LightGray" />

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="3" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="5" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="7" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="9" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="11" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="13" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="15" Fill="DarkGray" />

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="1" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="3" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="5" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="7" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="9" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="11" Fill="LightGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="13" Fill="DarkGray" />
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="15" Fill="LightGray" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```